# Хранение прайса в базе (интернет магазин)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite, oracle

В базе нужно хранить стоимость товара

Также нужно сделать курс и разные валюты

Какой тип должен быть в таблице базы?

Слышал что какие то проблемы при округлении или что то типа того, но так и не понял

(написал в ключах несколько типов баз для сравнения, основная будет mysql, но возможно будет и другая)

Спасибо

p.s. вот ссылка на статью
откопал
http://tarlyun.com/mysql/xranenie-ne-celyx-chisel-v-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

После запятой должно быть два знака и этого достаточно. Курс валют, насколько мне известно, имеет четыре знака после запятой. Но даже если вы делаете конверсию, будете приводить к двум знакам.

Валюты и их курсы лучше хранить в двух таблицах (одна для валют, другая для курсов валют) и получать курс на текущую дату хранимой функцией.

Answer (score 0):

У меня в магазине все во float(10, 2) - и курс, и цена. С округлением нет проблем.

Answer (score 0):

использую MySQL в системе учета товаров. как сказано выше - флоат(10,2) - и ничего больше.. хотя поставщики используют 3 знака после запятой, руки чешутся перейти к такому же формату, т. к. постоянно теряются деньги

Comment: Странно. Что может быть меньше одной копейки и больше 99 копеек?

Answer (score 0):

еще иногда принято использовать целочисленный тип и хранить цену, например, 25 рублей 30 копеек как 2530